# Im goining to connect Mysql using Spring boot Java. but i gave errors. im new for this

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)] [n/a]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'@'localhost' (using password: YES)] [n/a]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Execution failed for task ':SpringProApplication.main()'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
> You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
> For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
> BUILD FAILED in 12s
> 3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date

connect Mysql using Spring boot Java

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that could be going wrong here:

### 1. MySQL credentials are incorrect

Ensure that the username and password specified in your application.properties file are correct. The error message indicates that your credentials are incorrect, maybe there is a typo?

### 2. Use Correct MySQL Connector

Make sure you're using the correct MySQL connector version in your project dependencies that is compatible with your MySQL server version.

### My suggestion

When I started using Spring Boot these sort of things happened all the time. Based on what you've sent so far I assume your project is still pretty small. I would recommend to go to [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io) (I would recommend using Maven, but Gradle is just as good) and start from fresh. This is usually the fastest way to solve the problem. You can save the "Employee" and insert it into the project again.

If the database is empty, then rebuild that too.

##### While answering this I decided to try myself, this is what I used:

[Spring Initializr configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eru3c.png)

I configured my application.properties like so:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sbb_data
spring.datasource.username=sbb
spring.datasource.password=sbb
```

This is what my build.gradle looks like :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
  runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I ran the project it connected to the MySQL DB with no problems. My databases uses a simple user and password and not a root user, but it should work the same.

Give it a try and let me know if you still encounter issues

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you haven't filled out the application.yaml properties out properly, however there is so little information I can't be sure.

```
# In application.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabase
    username: root
    password: yourpassword
```

It would also be helpful if you provided more information such as the code you are running and the SQL configuration.

Comment: I will provide my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
application.Properties file

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect


--------------
SpringProApplictionTests.java file

package com.SpringPro.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

    @SpringBootTest
    class SpringProApplicationTests {
    
        @Test
        void contextLoads() {
        }

}
I created Employee and SpringProApplication.java file also
```

Comment: It looks like this was submitted before it was complete.  Please add commentary in addition to the code snippet.